# Postgres Delete Full outer join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to delete all `post` that do not contain a relation to `media`.

My select statement looks like this:

```
select post.*
from post full outer join media m on post.id = m.post_id where m is null;
```

How would the delete statement look like to delete all entries in the `post` table that do not have an entry in `media`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
delete from post p
    where not exists (select 1 from media m where p.id = m.post_id);
```